# How do I prevent a run-time error 13: type mismatch?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that will populate multiple columns either with a value or with a yellow color based on a drop-down selection. For example, the drop-down list contains two items, "YES" and "NO". When an item is selected, the adjacent two cells will populate with predetermined data, as shown below:

[image]

The above macro works until I right click and select "clear contents" to delete a range of values, as shown below:

[image]

Below is the code presenting the problem:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Select Case Target

  Case "YES"
    If Target = "YES" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

            If Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                Exit Sub
                    If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
            End If
    End If
  Case Else
    If Target = "NO" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = "NULL"
        Target.Offset(0, 2) = "NULL"
            If Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                Exit Sub
                    If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Sub
                            If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                    End If
            End If
    End If
  End Select
End Sub
```

I tried to figure out how to prevent this error many times, but I haven't been successful. I would appreciate any help in figuring this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add on the top the following:

`If Target.Count > 1 then Exit Sub`

Thus, you would exit the sub, whenever you have selected more than 1 cell.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vityata ! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @NickRivera - glad I was able to help :)

Comment: I forgot to mention..when I have selected more than one cell and right click and select "clear contents", the "NULL" values get deleted (which worked as requested), but not the yellow fill. Is there a way to clear the yellow fill as well? @Vityata

Comment: @NickRivera - I do not understand completely what is your aim, but try writing `Target.Clear` before the condition. It should clear anything. If this is not what you want, write `Target.Clear` in the condition.

Comment: My aim is to remove the yellow fill color of the two adjacent cells if I select "NO" in the same cell where "YES" was already selected. In other words, whenever I select either "YES" or "NO" the predetermined data adjusts accordingly to its requirements. I can open a new question for this, but I thought maybe this was something that could be done here. @Vityata

Comment: @NickRivera - did you try including `Target.Clear`? It will clear the yellow color.

Comment: Yes, I tried including Target.Clear, but it removed the data validation drop-down formatting in addition to the yellow fill. How does Target.Clear look in the visual basic editor the way you are describing it? @Vityata

Comment: @NickRivera try `target.Interior.color = vbWhite` instead of `Target.Clear`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you also want to copy/paste some "Yes"/"No" there and want it to be processed the correct way, this will do it in an easy short way:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim cell
  For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Columns(2)).Cells
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    ElseIf cell.Value = "No" Then
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = "NULL"
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
The range is set to `B1:B9999` because clearing the whole column may freeze excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("B1:B9999")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Dim cell
  For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("B1:B9999")).Cells
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
    ElseIf cell.Value = "No" Then
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = "NULL"
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    Else
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
  Next
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you want to only clear out "NULL" and undo the yellow color, you need to check each cell first like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("B1:B9999")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Dim cell
  For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("B1:B9999")).Cells
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
      If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NULL" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
      If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "NULL" Then cell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
    ElseIf cell.Value = "No" Then
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = "NULL"
      If cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
      If cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    Else
      If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NULL" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
      If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "NULL" Then cell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
      If cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
      If cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
  Next
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I used your code in place of mine. The macro doesn't enter "NULL" in the adjacent two cells if I select "NO" from the drop-down list. Similarly, if I select "YES", the macro doesn't enter  a yellow fill in the two adjacent cells. @Dirk Reichel

Comment: @NickRivera Tested it and got no problem. Still, I will run some additional tests and give feedback as soon as I am home again.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk Reichel . I'll test it again on my end as well.

Comment: @NickRivera got the problem: for some reason MY "Yes" and "No" was uppercase while the check is case sensitive :P Corrected the answer and added a solution to your increased problem. Also keep in mind that your code (also will mine) runs for ALL sheets!